# Decompressing 8GB Text file

Tags: tar, compression, decompression

I have a `.xz` file whose size is more than 8GB. I wonder if I can extract it without reading all of them at the same time.

Comment: what do you mean by "without reading all of them at the same time"?

Comment: @Zanna I mean, eventhough I'm not sure, I think during decompression the  decompression command will try to use at least the size of target file in memory. I dont want to do that.

Comment: Oh, you mean you think you will get an OOME? Please [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How much swap?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the .xz file and select `Open with Archive Manager`. Review the contents and extract only the single file that you desire.